# Delphi: Why Can I not use FMX.FORMS in a DYLIB

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, dylib, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am using the TMS FMX Cloud Pack. Throughout their code is liberally sprinkled FMX.Forms (and FMX.Dialogs which uses FMX.Forms). I currently use these libraries in a VCL DLL successfully.

My initial testing shows that, if I have FMX.Forms in the Uses clause of a DYLIB, the host application flashes in the MAC task bar and the application fails to start (I suspect because the DYLIB fails to load).

**EDIT:** I get this error when running from the Windows IDE through PAServer (I get no error when running from Finder on the MAC VM):

> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'
>   Runtime error 230 at 0015EA03

The simple test application is here: [Working HOST/DYLIB application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939045/delphi-fmx-osx-segmentation-fault-11/52939430?noredirect=1#comment92824842_52939430). If I simply add FMX.Forms to the uses clause I get the behaviour above.

Question 1: Is this expected behaviour?

Question 2: Is there a workaround (without removing FMX.Forms - since I use the TMS FMX Cloud Pack third party libraries)?

**EDIT:**

This appear to be the manifestation of this error "Unable to register class TFMXApplicationDelegate" when the application is run on a Physical Machine. The "Runtime Error 230" is what I get When I run the application within a Parallels macOS VM.

Regardless, the workaround to the "Unable to register class TFMXApplicationDelegate" issue is to NOT use FMX.Forms (or any unit that uses FMX.Forms in a DYLIB. All well and good, except that I am using (extensively) the TMS FMX Cloud Pack which uses FMX.Forms and FMX.Dialogs (which contains FMX.Forms) white liberally. Me trying to take out FMX.Forms etc from their code seems overly ambitious and, quite frankly, is getting to the point of why we buy third party libraries in the first place. If the just don't work, then they probably should not be used. And yes, I have emailed the Vendor.

But if anyone has any ideas how this might be resolved so that I can indeed use FMX.Forms in a DYLIB then please let me know.

Comment: Are there no errors that show in PAServer?

Comment: @DaveNottage, Sorry yes, there is a Runtime Error 230 if I run through PAServer I have edited original question with error, too big to fit in comment). If I just run from Finder then no error (that I can see). I'm getting confused. All of those 'unknown compression scheme' errors I seem to get whether the app succeeds or not.

Comment: Damn, now I remember why FMX.Forms was removed, If I run it on a Physical machine (as opposed to the Parallels VM) I an now getting the error: 'Unable to Register Class TFMXApplicationDelegate'. So I have come the complete circle. That's the culprit. I already posted a question about the TFMXApplicationDelegate error and the answer was to remove FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs (uses FMX.Forms) so not helpful.

Comment: @DaveNottage, I see your last comment is missing? Did you delete it?

Comment: Yes, because your next comment pretty much invalidated mine :-)

Comment: I am not sure whether I should resurrect the initial question with a workaround that actually doesn't solve this problem or continue here. I will update this questions first.

Comment: If you're able to debug the application (I cannot debug the example code right now), can you put breakpoints on each of the calls to FailRegistration in TRegisteredDelphiClass.RegisterClass in Macapi.ObjectiveC? It may help to know which one it fails on

Comment: I haven't had much luck debugging, but will try and get back ASAP.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. I am just not having any luck with the debugger in getting it to single step through the code. And just to screw things up, I installed Mojave on my Hard device and, of course, PAserver 19 does not work on it and is not scheduled until next year. I am about to revert back to my Time Machine backup overnight and restore high sierra.  messy. Where I will again address the debugging. Done everything per the Embarcadero documentation,I just don't seem to get anything near what I should be getting. The best I can do is have an error message appear on the host.